# Selection of first and last in non grouped item in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, group-by

Here's my table structure

```
Id  ToolName  ToolKey   ToolStatus
-----------------------------------    
1    XXXX      123      Running
2    XXXX      123      Completed
3    yyyy      134      Running
4    yyyy      134      Completed
```

I have grouped the above statement by toolname and toolkey.Here's my query

```
SELECT 
    TOOLNAME, ToolKey
FROM 
    TOOLS
GROUP BY 
    TOOLS.TOOLNAME, TOOLS.ToolKey
```

I need to have columns `ToolStatus1` with value `Running` and `ToolStatus2` with value `Completed`. If not completed means it should have null.

But in SQL if I add toolstatus in `grouping`, grouping will not be done.

In simple what I expect is like `First()` and `last()` as I will be having only two rows.

Let me know if unclear

Comment: Can you provide an example of output you are trying to achieve? I am not sure how you will relate status columns to Tool (i.e. how would you know toolstatus1 is for XXXX and ToolStatus2 is for yyyy?)

Comment: I need the rows like below

1   xxxx    123   Runing    Completed

1   xxxx    123   Running  Null (Not Completed)

Comment: It is not clear at all what you expect as output. Edit the question and clarify, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of options:

```
   SELECT TOOLNAME, 
           TOOLKEY, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN Toolstatus = 'Running' THEN 'Running' END) Toolstatus1, 
           MAX(CASE WHEN Toolstatus = 'Completed' THEN 'Completed' END) Toolstatus2
    FROM TOOLS
    GROUP BY TOOLNAME, 
             TOOLKEY
```

It *is* eliminating nulls with the aggregate MAX() function in this code, if that's a concern, you may want this:

```
SELECT TOOLNAME, 
       TOOLKEY, 
       [Running] Toolstatus1,
       [Completed] Toolstatus2
FROM (SELECT TOOLNAME, 
             TOOLKEY,
             TOOLSTATUS
      FROM TOOLS) AS src
PIVOT
(
MAX(TOOLSTATUS)
FOR TOOLSTATUS IN ([RUNNING], [COMPLETED])
) AS pvt
```